# Qt run 2 methods of the same object in two different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I've a class with some attributes and two methods. The methods need the same attributes and should run from programstart until the programm is terminated. The Methods don't need to interact with the GUI Thread.

Currently i only know how to move a complete object to another thread in Qt. But I need to run the two methods parallel. Is there any way?

Comment: The attributes need to be protected from concurrent access. It'd be safer to have a means of cloning your object so that both copies have the same attributes. The `moveToThread` API hints at this, as you've just acknowledged - it only lets you move a complete object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use QtConcurrent::run which runs function in a separate thread.

```
QFuture<void> future1 = QtConcurrent::run(this,&MyClass::Function1, arg1 );
QFuture<void> future2 = QtConcurrent::run(this,&MyClass::Function2, arg1 );
```

You can check the state of the asynchronous computation represented by these futures like:

```
if(future1.isRunning())
{
    // It is currently running
}
```

Or wait for it to finish:

```
future1.waitForFinished();
```

Comment: Of course this doesn't solve the problem of it being generally an error to access the object's attributes from two threads at once.

Comment: It works. can you tell me what (this,&MyClass::Function) make? I can't find a matching signature of run in the refrence.

Comment: The first is the object of the class containing the function and the second is a pointer to a function in a class.

Comment: you need to look in qtbase/src/concurrent/qtconcurrentrun.h to find the template specialization that will work with the above. QFuture<T> run(Class *object, T (Class::*fn)(Param1), const Arg1 &arg1) is one example. Maybe there will be variadic templates soon here too. Documentation is simplified.